# Split reducers operating on the same slice of data in redux

Tags: redux

I have a store which is shaped like this:

```
{
  // ...data

  user: {
    warranties: {
      W_1: ['O_1', 'O_2'],
      W_2: ['O_3', 'O_4']   
    }
  }
}
```

Where keys starting with `W_` are warranties, keys starting with `O_` are options.

For each **warranty** I have one or more **options** associated to it, relations in `user.warranties` are in the form: `warranty => [options]`.

To achieve it I'm combining my reducers like this:

```
rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // ...other main reducers

  user: combineReducers({
    // ...other user reducers
    warranties
  })
})
```

---

Now, the "*problem*" is that both `USER_WARRANTY` and `USER_OPTION` actions are handled by the same reducer, because:

- When I add an option, I need to push it to the correct warranty entry.
- Inversely when I add a warranty I need to populate it with its default options.
- And ultimately, they operate on the same slice of data

So the `warranties` reducer, has to react to both actions, looking like this:

```
export default function warranties(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_WARRANTIES_ADD:
    // add warranty key to `user.warranties`

    case USER_WARRANTIES_REMOVE:
    // remove warranty key from `user.warranties`

    case USER_OPTIONS_ADD:
    // push option to `user.warranties[warrantyID]`

    case USER_OPTIONS_REMOVE:
    // remove option from `user.warranties[warrantyID]`

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I would like to split this in two reducers, `warranties` and `options`, but still have them operate on the same slice of data.

Ideally I would then compose my root reducer like this:

```
rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // ...other main reducers

  user: combineReducers({
    // ...other user reducers
    warranties: magicalCombine({
      warranties,
      options
    })
  })
})
```

Where `magicalCombine` is the function I am having troubles to find.

---

I have tried [`reduce-reducers`](https://github.com/redux-utilities/reduce-reducers), but looks like the second reducer (`options`) is never actually reached, and I'm actually unsure about it since I'm not trying to achieve flat state, but actually operate on the same key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reducer is simple a function that take `state` and `action` and returns a new state object, so I think this would do what you want..

```
rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // ...other main reducers

  user: combineReducers({
    // ...other user reducers
    warranties: (state, action) => {
      // state is state.user.warranties
      // we pass it to each reducer in turn and return the result
      state = warranties(state, action);
      return options(state, action);
    }
  })
})
```

using reduceReducers should do the same thing (I haven't used it before, but that's what it looks like..)

```
rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // ...other main reducers

  user: combineReducers({
    // ...other user reducers
    warranties: reduceReducers(warranties, options)
  })
})
```

`combineReducers` from redux is simply intentionally restricted to pass only the value of the state property that matches the key in the reducers object provided to it, it's not really special in any other way. see more here.. https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/beyondcombinereducers